# Rails 5 - Friendship Status Detection Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm in the middle of creating a social network and I'm receiving an `uninitialized constant User::Friendship` error when I put:

```
<p><%= action_buttons(user)%></p>
```

in my `users/index.html.erb` file, here is my `user.rb` file:

```
has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :inverse_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: "friend_id", dependent: :destroy

  def request_friendship(user_2)
    self.friendships.create(friend: user_2)
  end

  def pending_friend_requests_from
    self.inverse_friendships.where(state: "pending")
  end

  def pending_friend_requests_to
    self.friendships.where(state: "pending")
  end

  def active_friends
    self.friendships.where(state: "active").map(&:friend) + self.inverse_friendships.where(state: "active").map(&:user)
  end

  def friendship_status(user_2)
    friendship = Friendship.where(user_id: [self.id,user_2.id], friend_id: [self.id,user_2.id])
    unless friendship.any?
      return "not_friends"
    else
      if friendship.first.state == "active"
        return "friends"
      else
        if friendship.first.user == self
          return "pending"
        else
          return "requested"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def friendship_relation(user_2)
    Friendship.where(user_id: [self.id,user_2.id], friend_id: [self.id,user_2.id]).first
  end
```

I'm using Devise by the way.

Friendship class file

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
  def accept_friendship
    self.update_attributes(state: "active", friended_at: Time.now)
  end
  def deny_friendship
    self.destroy
  end
  def cancel_friendship
    self.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: it can't evaluate the Friendship constant, can you provide your Friendship class code?

Comment: Sure can class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"

 def accept_friendship
  self.update_attributes(state: "active", friended_at: Time.now)
 end

 def deny_friendship
  self.destroy
 end

 def cancel_friendship
  self.destroy
 end
end

Comment: Is there a line number on the error? It would help us narrow down which of those is the problem

Comment: yes friendship = Friendship.where(user_id: [self.id,user_2.id], friend_id: [self.id,user_2.id]) this is in the user.rb file

Comment: Can you post the full error stack trace?